# Dividing a number by instances of my class in Python

Tags: python, math, division

I have a class called `Time`, and I need to implement a `Frequency` class. How can I implement dividing `int`s or `float`s by an instance of `Time` to get an instance of `Frequency` ?

I already know about `__div__`, `__truediv__`, `__floordiv__` and other Python special methods, and I already use them in my code to divide instances of classes by numbers or instances of other classes, but I cannot find a way to divide a number by an instance of my class.

Is it possible to implement dividing a number by an instance of a class in Python ?

Comment: Having a different class for every type of quantity sounds like a road to madness... How are you handling mismatches between units?

Comment: I use `isinstance`, and I only had to implement Time and Frequency.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The `__rtruediv__` method is what you're looking for.
When `x / y` is executed, if `type(x)` does not implement a `__div__(self, other)` method where `other` can be of class `type(y)`, then `type(y).__rtruediv__(y, x)` is executed, and its result is returned.

Usage:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        return self.x / other

    def __rtruediv__(self, other):
        return other / self.x
```

```
>>> f = Foo(10)    
>>> f / 10
1.0
>>> 10 / f
1.0
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes. You just have to make sure that `Time.__rtruediv__()` returns a `Frequency` instance when it receives a float or integer.

Usage:

```
>>> 100 / Time(2)
Frequency(50.0)
>>> 2.5 / Time(5)
Frequency(0.5)
```

Implementation:

```
class Time:
  def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value

  def __rtruediv__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, (int, float)):
      return NotImplemented
    return Frequency(other / self.value)

class Frequency:
  def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value

  def __repr__(self):
    return '{}({})'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self.value)
```

The python docs contains a full example on [implementing the arithmetic operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html#implementing-the-arithmetic-operations) for your custom classes.

The proper way to handle incompatible types is to return the special value `NotImplemented`.

> [**NotImplemented**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#NotImplemented)
>
> Special value which should be returned by the binary
>   special methods (e.g. `__eq__()`, `__lt__()`, `__add__()`, `__rsub__()`, etc.)
>   to indicate that the operation is not implemented with respect to the
>   other type

Suppose you try to use a unsupported complex number, returning `NotImplemented` will eventually cause a `TypeError` with a correct error message. (at least in python 3)

```
>>> 100j / Time(2)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'complex' and 'Time'
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to implement `__rtruediv__` and`__rfloordiv__`.

from [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__)

```
object.__radd__(self, other)
object.__rsub__(self, other)
object.__rmul__(self, other)
object.__rmatmul__(self, other)
object.__rtruediv__(self, other)
object.__rfloordiv__(self, other)
object.__rmod__(self, other)
object.__rdivmod__(self, other)
object.__rpow__(self, other)
object.__rlshift__(self, other)
object.__rrshift__(self, other)
object.__rand__(self, other)
object.__rxor__(self, other)
object.__ror__(self, other)
```

> These methods are called to implement the binary arithmetic operations
>   (+, -, *, @, /, //, %, divmod(), pow(), **, <<, >>, &, ^, |) with
>   reflected (swapped) operands. These functions are only called if the
>   left operand does not support the corresponding operation [3] and the
>   operands are of different types. [4] For instance, to evaluate the
>   expression x - y, where y is an instance of a class that has an
>   `__rsub__()` method, `y.__rsub__(x)` is called if `x.__sub__(y)` returns NotImplemented.