# create function that lets you divide variables with multiple paramaters

Tags: python, python-3.x

Making a food log that has multiple entries. Each entry has name, calories, fat, carbs, protein, serving size, in that order.

IE:

chicken_salad_sandwich  =
*FoodValues('Chicken Salad Sandwich', calories=600, fat=18, carbs=48, protein=25, serv_size=250)*

**How do I write code that lets me divide the item in whatever manner I desire?**

This is what I want to return if I divide variable 'chicken_salad_sandwich ' by two:

*FoodValues('Chicken Salad Sandwich', calories=300, fat=9, carbs=24, protein=12.5, serv_size=125)*

Here's the code that *multiplies*:

```
def __mul__(self, other):
    if other == 0:
        return 0

    # Other than 0, food values can only be multiplied by an int
    if not isinstance(other, int):
        return NotImplemented

    selfname = self.name
    if '+' in selfname:
        # Quick and dirty grouping symbol
        selfname = f'({selfname})'

    return FoodValues(
        f'{other} {selfname}',
        self.fat * other,
        self.carbs * other,
        self.protein * other,
        self.serv_size * other,
        self.calories * other,
    )
```

Comment: Could you update the class itself, or do you want to return a new one? EDIT: `__div__` should do it. Not quite sure what question you are asking.

Comment: @LarrytheLlama I have bolded the question. I already have a function that lets me multiple whatever item I want. Now I want to write one that lets me divide accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Re-wrote your code for `__div__`. I believe this is what you are asking for (I also made it divide only by `int`)

```
def __div__(self, other):
    if other == 0:
        return 0

    # Other than 0, food values can only be divided by an int
    if not isinstance(other, int):
        return NotImplemented

    selfname = self.name
    if '+' in selfname:
        # Quick and dirty grouping symbol
        selfname = f'({selfname})'

    return FoodValues(
        f'{other} {selfname}',
        self.fat / other,
        self.carbs / other,
        self.protein / other,
        self.serv_size / other,
        self.calories / other,
    )
```

(I believe it is **div**, let me know if not)

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and got this error: 'TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'FoodValues' and 'int'' Error occurs where I tried to divide a value inside a sum function: bkfast = sum([shugs_bacon_egg_chz_bagel / 2,fairlife_choc_milk]). I am trying to divide the item shugs_bacon_egg_chz_bagel by two. Then return the sum of half the shugs bagel and and the addition of item fairlife_chocmilk.

Comment: @poptart20 you might be able to edit the tag to `__rtruediv__`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44970692/dividing-a-number-by-instances-of-my-class-in-python/44971166

Comment: Dude that worked. Thank you so much Larry!